# How to test ngAfterViewInit in Angular using jest

Tags: angular, jestjs

I have this `ngAfterViewInit` function:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.dataService.wsData$.pipe(first()).subscribe(() => {
        this.isDataLoaded = true;
        this.antiScroller.preventLoadScroll();
      });
    });
  }
```

`wsData$` is defined in another file as shown below:

`public wsData$ = new ReplaySubject<OverviewMetrics>(1);`

How do I write the test case for this function? I tried

`it('should call after view init', () => { component.ngAfterViewInit(); expect(component.isDataLoaded).toBe(true); });`

This is not working.

My complete `spec` file looks like this:

```
import { waitForAsync, ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { createComponent, Page, provideMockObject } from '@webex/common/test-utils';
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { DataService } from 'src/app/services/data.service';
import { FeatureService } from '../../utility/feature.service';
import { BehaviorSubject, ReplaySubject, Subscription, interval, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { OverviewpageComponent } from './overviewpage.component';
import { OverviewMetrics } from '../interfaces/overview-metrics';

const wsData$ = new ReplaySubject<OverviewMetrics>(1);

const MockFeatureService = {
  isProductEnabled: jest.fn()
}

const deviceTrendCardSections = [
  {
    sectionHeader: 'Call Activity',
    cards: [
      {
        chartTitle: 'Calls Completed (Delta*)',
        tooltip: 'Displays a trend chart of the calls that are completed for each call processing node in the selected cluster.',
        counterKey: 'getCallActivityReply_CallsCompleted',
        tableDescriptionTitle: 'Servers',
        tableValueTitle: 'Usage',
        topCount: 5,
      },

    ],
  },
  {
    sectionHeader: 'Trunk Activity',
    selectedSubsection: 'SIP',
    subsections: [
      {
        sectionType: 'H323',
        cards: [
          {
            chartTitle: 'Calls Completed',
            tooltip: 'Displays a trend chart of the calls that are completed for each call processing node that are routed via a H323 trunk.',
            counterKey: 'H323_Trunk_CallsCompleted',
            tableDescriptionTitle: 'Servers',
            tableValueTitle: 'Usage',
            topCount: 5,
          },
          {
            chartTitle: 'Calls In Progress',
            tooltip: 'Displays a trend chart of the calls that are in progress for each call processing node that are routed via a H323 trunk.',
            counterKey: 'H323_Trunk_CallsInProgress',
            tableDescriptionTitle: 'Servers',
            tableValueTitle: 'Usage',
            topCount: 5,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        sectionType: 'SIP',
        cards: [
          {
            chartTitle: 'Calls Completed',
            tooltip: 'Displays a trend chart of the calls that are completed for each call processing node that is routed via a SIP trunk.',
            counterKey: 'SIP-Trunk_CallsCompleted',
            tableDescriptionTitle: 'Servers',
            tableValueTitle: 'Usage',
            topCount: 5,
          },
          {
            chartTitle: 'Calls In Progress',
            tooltip: 'Displays a trend chart of the calls that are in progress for each call processing node that is routed via a SIP trunk.',
            counterKey: 'SIP-Trunk_CallsInProgress',
            tableDescriptionTitle: 'Servers',
            tableValueTitle: 'Usage',
            topCount: 5,
          }
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];


class OverviewComponentPage extends Page<OverviewpageComponent> {
  constructor(fixture: ComponentFixture<OverviewpageComponent>) {
    super(fixture);
  }

  get rtmtResourceCardComponent() {
    return this.elementQueryAll('rtmt-resource-card');
  }

  get tabsComponent() {
    return this.elementQueryAll('md-tab-pane');
  }
}

describe('OverviewpageComponent', () => {
  let component: OverviewpageComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<OverviewpageComponent>;
  let page: OverviewComponentPage;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ OverviewpageComponent ],
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        provideMockObject(FeatureService),
        provideMockObject(DataService),
        {
          provide: FeatureService,
          useValue: MockFeatureService
        }
      ],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    ({ fixture, component, page } = createComponent(OverviewpageComponent, OverviewComponentPage));
    component.deviceTrendCardSections = deviceTrendCardSections;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should contain RTMT Resource Card component to display the line charts', () => {
    expect(page.rtmtResourceCardComponent).toBeTruthy();
  })

  it('should contain 3 tabs', () => {
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(page.tabsComponent.length).toBe(3);
  });

  it('should call after view init', () => {
    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    expect(component.isDataLoaded).toBe(true);
  });
```

When I add `DataService` as `provideMockObject(DataService)` in providers, I get the below error:

[image]

How do I write the test for `ngAfterInit` ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `provideMockObject` ? Otherwise mock your dataservice with the Observable:

```
{
    provide: DataService,
    useValue: {
        wsData$: of(true)
    }
},
```

Also beside your isDataLoaded validation, your expectation shoud check if preventLoadScroll has been called.

Edit:

```
  it('should call after view init', () => {
    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    fixture.detectCahnges();
    setTimeout(()=>{
     expect(component.isDataLoaded).toBe(true);
    },100)
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I tried adding the useValue as you mentioned. And updated my test as : `it('should call after view init', () => {
    component.ngAfterViewInit();
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(component.isDataLoaded).toBe(true);
  });`   . But, its still gives the same error. `Expected: true , Received: false`

Comment: you tried to add a little timeout in your test too before checking isDataLoaded ?

Comment: Still 1 error is showing up . `TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventLoadScroll' of undefined`. I added the provider of that Module as well `provideMockObject(AntiScrollerDirective),` . What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You provide an invalid mock object.